# React-Native-FS ANY filepath gives me "ENOENT: no such file or directory"

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fs

Any value I put in for firmwareFilePath gives me "ENOENT: no such file or directory".

```
const firmwareFilePath = "./assets/BLE_chef.bin";
const firmwareData = RNFS.readFile(firmwareFilePath, 'base64');
```

Even RNFS.exists gives me a false.
I'm trying to run this on ios device, how do i get it to actually find the files?